# having difficulties analyzing recursive steps of a function

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, tree, ocaml

I'm currently studying OCaml for a functional programming exam and I'm having some difficulties trying to follow the steps of this recursive function in this exercise. The task is to find the most expensive leaf in a int N-ary tree (a leaf cost is given by the sum of integers on the path to a leaf).

This is the type definition:

```
type 'a ntree = Ntree of 'a * 'a ntree list
```

this is an auxiliary function for the exercise

```
let rec maxpair = function
  | [] -> failwith "empty list"
  | [(x, y)] -> (x, y)
  | (x, y) :: (a, b) :: rest -> 
      if y > b then maxpair ((x, y) :: rest) 
      else maxpair ((a, b) :: rest)
```

and finally here's the final function

```
let rec leaf_cost = function
  | Ntree (x, []) -> (x, x)
  | Ntree (x, tlist) -> 
      let (y, c) = maxpair (List.map leaf_cost tlist)
      in 
      (y, c + x)
```

This is the solution of the exercise, meaning it works. But I'm having trouble trying to analyze every recursive step in the function, especially because I'm a bit confused about the `let (y, c) ... in (y, c + x)` declaration.

Comment: Is your question specifically about the meaning of `let ... in ...`? If so, that is just a way of doing an assignment with a scope. In another language you might have written `(y,c) = maxpair (List.map leaf_cost tlist); return (y, c+x)`

Comment: let (y,c) = maxpair (List.map leaf_cost tlist) is called a local binding,a nd by local it means it will be visible and accessible only in the scope in which they are defined. That line, specifically creates 2 name-bindings, namely, y and c which then gets used after the "in" (y, c+x).. the values of y and c comes from the local binding which we created in the previous line.

Comment: If your question is about `List.map`: it applies a function to every element of a list, and returns the list of results. For instance `List.map f [1;2;3]` is equivalent to `[f 1; f 2; f 3]`.

Comment: Maybe also worth noting that cases like `| [(x, y)] -> (x, y)` are needlessly complex. If you're not testing the contents of that tuple, and you just need to handle there being one item in the list, you could more concisely write `| [x] -> x`.

Comment: You may also wish to have `maxpair` return an option type value when given `[]` rather than using an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a tree, `leaf_cost` returns a pair `(v, c)` which is the value of the leaf node with the maximal cost `v`, and that cost `c`.

In the base case, when there is no child node, the value is `x` and its cost is also `x`.

In the general case, a node is made of an integer `x` and list of child node `children` (aka `tlist`).

```
List.map leaf_cost children
```

The above expression is a list of pairs, each one being the maximum leaf and its associated cost in the respective subtree rooted in each child node.

In general, there might be multiple leaves with the same cost, but your problem ignores that and selects, in an implementation-defined way, a pair with the maximal cost among all costs so far.

This is done by calling `maxpair`, which gives a pair `(y, c)` where `y` is the first leaf having the maximal cost `c` among all the pairs obtained recursively.

Knowing that among all subtrees, `(y, c)` is a leaf with cost `c`, and that your current node weights `x`, the cost of the current node is `c + x`. That's why the returned value in the general case is `(y, c+x)`, keeping track of the leaf in the subtrees that lead to this cost.